# Run AngularJS in WebView Windows 8.1

Tags: .net, angularjs, webview, windows-8.1, windows

everybody.

I'm using an application in Windows 8.1 (desktop) that has a WebView that load a website in in AngularJS. This site is local, all files generated by AngularJS are in the application in Assets/MySite.

When I put the content generated by AngularJS in WebView itself does not render correctly. When I run the site through IIS the site works perfectly.

The question is, can I load a WebView with a Web service? Case the AngularJS just works with a service web, right?.

If I do:

```
webView.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Assets/MySite/index.html");
```

Doesn't work.

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here!

[A simple in-process HTTP server for Windows 8 Metro apps](http://www.dzhang.com/blog/2012/09/18/a-simple-in-process-http-server-for-windows-8-metro-apps)

Tks